# mysql trigger delete on same id

Tags: mysql, triggers

with a TRIGGER I want to delete a row in table2 with the same id than the one deleted in table1

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgDeleteInTable2 AFTER DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE  FROM table2 a  WHERE a.id =  the same id than the one deleted in table1 
END;
```

how can I do it ? how can I get the current id deleted in table1 ?

thanks for helping

Comment: Best is to use InnoDB engine and use foreign keys with on delete cascade.. Right now you are using application code to do something the database nativly supports so you dont have to write a trigger your it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgDeleteInTable2 AFTER DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE * FROM table2 a  WHERE a.id =  OLD.id 
END;
```

`OLD.id` is the `id` from `table1` which was deleted.