# How to auto delete with AFTER DELETE TRIGGER 2 table rows when user deletes table row on a 3rd table on 3 different databases on same mySQL server?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to all this. I need help with AFTER DELETE.

My situation:

- Database 1 - Main Users - email
- Database 2 - users - email
- Database 3 - users - email

All databases on same mySQL server being accessed with phpAdmin.

When a user deletes their row on database 1, table name - main users, I want the same table rows for the same user to be auto deleted in users tables in databases 2 and 3.  I am using email to identify the users on all 3 database tables. I tried with 2 database tables first using the examples cited in the links but am getting an error. Here is my trigger and error.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER user_after_delete AFTER DELETE on  database1.Main_Users

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Database2.users 
    WHERE Database2.users.email = old.Database1.Main_Users.email;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.email;
>
> END' at line 6

Where am I going wrong? how I could include all 3 databases on same server in same AFTER DELETE TRIGGER?

I tried to follow the examples given below without success:

- [mysql trigger delete on same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943826/mysql-trigger-delete-on-same-id;)
- [MySQL Trigger: Delete From Table AFTER DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818191/mysql-trigger-delete-from-table-after-delete?noredirect=1&lq=1).

EDIT

I tried this

DELETE FROM Database2.users WHERE Database2.users.email = old.email;

it worked but was I supposed to create this trigger in database 1 because I lost all my rows on both databases? Luckily have backups.

UPDATE

I solved it. I pasted the code inside phpAdmin trigger. I just kept and the body inside Begin and End. Thank you everyone.

Comment: old.Database1.Main_Users.email -- old.email should be enough the create trigger has specified the db and table btw which db are you creating this trigger in?

Comment: I am using db 2 SQL box. Thank you for inspecting my query.

Comment: Also I am using mySQL version 5.7 if it helps. Thank you

Comment: @P.Salmon, was I supposed to create trigger in database 1? your suggested old.email removed the error but all the rows on both databases were affected. Thank you.